# In R, how to automatically analyze statistical test (i.e., ANOVA) per treatment, without manually specifying each treatment?

Tags: r, subset, anova

For example, I have the following data.

```
Cultivar=rep(c("CV1","CV2"),each=12)
Nitrogen=rep(rep(c("N0","N1","N2","N3"), each=3),2)
Block=rep(c("I","II","III"),8)
Yield=c (99, 109, 89, 115, 142, 133, 121, 157, 142, 125, 
         150, 139, 82, 104, 99, 117, 125, 127, 145, 154, 
         154, 151, 166, 175)
dataA=data.frame(Cultivar,Nitrogen,Block,Yield)

   Cultivar Nitrogen  Block  Yield
1  CV1       N0       I      99
2  CV1       N0       II     109
3  CV1       N0       III    89
4  CV1       N1       I      115
5  CV1       N1       II     142
6  CV1       N1       III    133
7  CV1       N2       I      121
8  CV1       N2       II     157
9  CV1       N2       III    142
10 CV1       N3       I      125
11 CV1       N3       II     150
12 CV1       N3       III    139
13 CV2       N0       I      82
14 CV2       N0       II     104
15 CV2       N0       III    99
16 CV2       N1       I      117
17 CV2       N1       II     125
18 CV2       N1       III    127
19 CV2       N2       I      145
20 CV2       N2       II     154
21 CV2       N2       III    154
22 CV2       N3       I      151
23 CV2       N3       II     166
24 CV2       N3       III    175
```

I'd like to do ANOVA per cultivar. So, I use the code below:

```
ANOVA=aov(Yield~Nitrogen +factor(Block), data=subset(dataA, Cultivar=="CV1"))
summary(ANOVA)
```

It seems okay, but in my actual data, I have 30 cultivars, so it's not possible to divide the data by cultivar 30 times manually. I believe there is a way to analyze the data per cultivar automatically without using `subset()` in R.

Could you please let me know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take YH's answer one step further, this type of problem fits well with  a split, apply, merge approach.

```
#split into a list of data frames by Cultivar column
splitdata <- split(dataA, dataA$Cultivar)

#apply the Anova function to the list of data frames
lapply(splitdata, function(df) {
   ANOVA=aov(Yield~Nitrogen +factor(Block), data=df)
   summary(ANOVA)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do with `lapply()`

```
treatment = unique(dataA$Cultivar)
lapply(treatment, \(x){
  ANOVA=aov(Yield~Nitrogen +factor(Block), dataA[dataA$Cultivar == x,])
  summary(ANOVA)
}) |> 
  setNames(treatment)
```

**Output**

```
$CV1
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Nitrogen       3   3248  1082.7   19.14 0.00179 **
factor(Block)  2   1206   603.2   10.66 0.01059 * 
Residuals      6    340    56.6                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

$CV2
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
Nitrogen       3   8486  2828.7  136.88 6.5e-06 ***
factor(Block)  2    546   273.0   13.21 0.00634 ** 
Residuals      6    124    20.7                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```